# In Google Analytics 4, how do I link AdSense?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

I have previously had AdSense and Google Analytics linked, then I decided to upgrade to the latest [Google Analytics 4 (formerly known as App + Web)](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/analytics/new_google_analytics/)

Under this new Analytics I have no AdSense data under my monetization tab.

[image]

Most suggestions online I think are outdated (or else there's something else going on), they suggest going to `Admin -> Account -> Property -> PRODUCT LINKING`.  However when I go there there is no option for AdSense :

[image]

In contrast, in the old Universal Analytics there is an option for AdSense

[image]

So how can I link AdSense to the new Google Analytics 4?

Comment: This Adsense linking is still not available and it’s really reckless by Google to be forcing users to transition to a platform that is still not production ready.

Answer (score 7):

It's my understanding that GA4 does not yet offer this functionality. GA4 is not yet totally production ready, hence why the upgrade documentation recommends installing both GA3 and GA4 together, so as to have the benefits of GA3 functionality and reporting, while learning the GA4 interface, and reporting/analysis features as it gains upgrades and improvements.

Comment: This is pretty stupid thing that Google did. All the publishers that are out there are not important to them?

Comment: Think they have changed this as of just very recently and it now works for publishers